# What are the benefits of using react-router over kadira:flow-router for meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, react-router, flow-router

I am new to meteor and react. I have been searching for the best practices for developing my voting-based project with meteor and react. One of the problems I tried to find on internet is pros and cons of using one of two options for router in meteor.

kadira:flow-router seems pretty straightforward to implement, but I see lots of projects on github implementing react-router instead.

Any idea about the comparison of both router packages for meteor ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you focus on Meteor with React, I recommend **flow-router**.
If not, choose **react-router** or **redux-router**(for redux).

I have to say, react-router use a lot of skills with react concept,
like writing router JSX component and use context to dispatch its url params. If you try to go deep, you will learn more about react itself. That will help you construct app beyond Meteor, and is why I recommend react-router.